# is supposed to HAVE DONE

Tags: meaning

This pattern - "is supposed to HAVE DONE" is used in sentences some of which are considered wrong but others are considered correct. I can't fathom what makes them wrong or correct. For example:

1 **I am supposed to have bought milk yesterday. - WRONG**

2 **Why are you here? You are supposed to have gone to school. - CORRET**

Why is 1 wrong but 2 is correct?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with sentence 1, other than being a little stilted ("I was supposed to buy milk yesterday" is a lot more likely). That being the case, I'm not sure anyone can tell you in detail "why" it's correct if you don't have reasoning for why it's wrong.

Comment: But you yourself say that you would replace it with "I was supposed to buy milk yesterday". If you consider it correct, disclose the difference between  them.

Comment: It's a little overly formal, but that doesn't mean it's wrong. We don't tend to use a perfect tense when we can say the same thing in a simple tense, especially in conversation. Then again, I have the impression that's a little less true in BrE, so maybe someone would disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the sentence

> I am supposed to have bought milk yesterday

is "wrong" while the sentence

> You are supposed to have gone to school.

is "correct" is really a matter of *semantics* and not *syntax*. In other words, it's a *meaning* issue, not a grammar issue. BOTH sentences are grammatically correct.

However, the first sentence doesn't actually mean what the speaker most likely intended. (That's what makes it "wrong.") As @the-baby-is-you commented, the speaker probably intended the same meaning as the alternative

> **3.** I was supposed to buy milk yesterday.

But, the construction "for [S] to be supposed to [do something]" has two possible meanings: either S is *obliged/advised/ordered* to do the thing, or S is *thought/believed* to do the thing. The word "supposed" is actually pronounced two different ways, depending on which meaning is being used! The "obliged" meaning has an "s" sound, while the "believed" meaning has a "z" sound.

When the main verb of the sentence is in the *present* tense, as it is in both your sentences ("am" and "are"), the logical inference is that the speaker is talking about the *present*, not the past, even though both sentences contain a reference to a past action (i.e. *to have bought milk yesterday* and *to have gone to school*). So, the speaker is talking about the present effect of past actions.

Given this, the **second** sentence makes sense with the "obligated" meaning of "supposed": the speaker (presumably the child's parent) is referring to a present state (that of *the child's not being in school when they ought to*) resulting from a past action (presumably that of *not getting on the bus*).

But, does the **first** sentence also make sense with this meaning of "supposed"? Not really -- if the person failed to buy milk *yesterday*, it's likely a moot point *today* -- so it doesn't make sense to talk about them being in a present state of "ought-to-have-bought-milk-ness." While the first situation can be remedied in the present (the parent driving the child to school), the second *can't* (if the person buys milk *now*, it won't fix the *not having had the milk when it was needed earlier*.)

So, since the more likely intended meaning of "supposed" isn't logical here, the other, less-likely meaning would actually fit the first sentence's syntax better:

> I am *believed* (by someone) to have bought milk yesterday

But, this meaning is unlikely -- it seems like an unusual idea for someone to be expressing. So, it's the fact that the structure doesn't fit the intended meaning, but instead causes ambiguity by suggesting an *unintended* meaning, that makes the first sentence wrong. @the-baby-is-you's alternative sentence (with the past tense main verb and present infinitive, instead of a present tense main verb and perfect infinitive) avoids the ambiguity, and so is a more correct way of expressing that idea.